# Join data objects by date but with different intervals

Tags: r, date, merge, intervals, lubridate

I have ran into this issue and I really have no clue how to do it. I have two data.frames, both with date columns. However, the first one, which is a big object, contains measurements each 3 seconds, while the second contains measurements each 10 minutes. I want to include the measurement variable of object 2 into object 1 (something like a left_join or merge) by the date variable. My data looks like this (df1):

| date_time | measurement1 |
| --- | --- |
| yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:03 | val1 |
| yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:06 | val2 |

df2:

| date_time | measurement2 |
| --- | --- |
| yyyy-mm-dd HH:10:00 | val1 |
| yyyy-mm-dd HH:20:00 | val2 |

I hope that is enough info, otherwise please comment. I have explored foverlapse and fuzzyjoin but without success.

Thank you in advance

Here is what I have in a bit more detail (df1):

| date_time | measurement1 |
| --- | --- |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:03 | 73 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:06 | 73.5 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:09 | 48.5 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:12 | 50.7 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:15 | 80 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:18 | 81 |

Data continue for a number of months every time each 3 seconds

df2:

| date_time | measurement2 |
| --- | --- |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:00 | 110 |
| 05/06/2018 0:10:00 | 120 |
| 05/06/2018 0:20:00 | 180 |

What I want is this:

df:

| date_time | measurement1 | measurement2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:03 | 73 | 110 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:06 | 73.5 | 110 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:09 | 48.5 | 110 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:12 | 50.7 | 110 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:15 | 80 | 110 |
| 05/06/2018 0:00:18 | 81 | 110 |

I hope now is clearer, by the way, there might be an issue with tables, I am using the format I am told by Stack overflow and I can see the tables being produced in the review, but then the format is lost when I submit.

Thank you

Comment: You should offer some data and show what you intend to do with one or two intervals of whatever level of aggregation you desire. If it's by day then you need to tell us if you wnat means, minima, maxima or standard deviations for each day, or perhaps all of the above. At any rate you need to specify the analysis rather than expecting us to read you (or your boss's) mind.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It is not to compute means or standard deviation by aggregation. What I want is measurement 2 included in df1. The values of measurement 2 are taken each 10 minutes and the ones of measurement 1 in df1 each 3 seconds. Therefore, I expect each individual value of measurement 2 on df2 to be repeated several times when passed to df1. I will add a more thorough example soon enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every minute has 20 observations if those observations occur every 3 seconds. Hence, there are 200 observations for every 10 minute interval. **If** your data is complete, then it would suffice that you stretch out your seconds 10-minute-interval observations accordingly, i.e. you copy every 10-minute-interval value 200 times next to the 3-second-interval values.

Try the following and tell me what you get

```
df1$measurement2 <- rep(df2$measurement2, each = 200)
```

Comment: It is a smart solution, however the data is not complete (only the second dataframe can be considered complete as it covers all the 2018 year). I will try adding empty rows to the incomplete dataframe

Comment: Ok, if the solution nevertheless helped you, you might indicate that with an upvote + accept.

Comment: Very glad to help you, Daniel!